# Why is my button not appearing on the page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, forms, button

I have this form in a partial:

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @profile.user.id) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <div class="follow_button"><%= f.submit "Follow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

that is rendered to my profile view. Here is the resulting html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/relationships" class="new_relationship" id="new_relationship" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="fo9dve4XjKpqSHqkmYw/lsEPm4PUxRYy+5JM5D4aTLg="></div>
    <div><input id="relationship_followed_id" name="relationship[followed_id]" type="hidden" value="58"></div>
    <div class="follow_button"><input id="relationship_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Follow"></div>
</form>
```

The form is there, and the css display attribute for the button is not hidden, so why is the button not appearing?

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what I did  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something else in your CSS file is causing the submit button to be hidden. Try disabling your CSS styles for the entire page and see if the button is still hidden.

Comment: yeah it's something in my css

Comment: Use Firefox with the Firebug add-on to inspect the button and figure out what css style is causing the button to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the CSS class "follow_button" from the button. If the button then appears. Then the problem is in the styles.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my buttons one time, then I realized that I had not linked my html and css for the specific tab I wanted to have a button. So always make sure to double check that